# Bijection between $X^\omega$ and $B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The following is an exercise from *Topology* by Munkres.

> Let $X=\{0,1\}$, $X^\omega=\prod\limits^\infty X$, and $B=\{\text{all countable subsets of $X^\omega$}\}$. 
>   Show that $|X^\omega|=|B|$.

**My attempt:** I can't seem to find a particular bijection, so I want to use Schröder-Bernstein and find two injective functions using each set as its domain and range, respectively. 
It is easy to see that the function $f:X^\omega\to B$ defined as $f(x)=\{x\}$ is an injection. However, I can't seem to find a function $g:B\to X^\omega$ that is injective.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's a tricky one to do. You can't *define* an injection in the other direction, since proving such injection exists requires the axiom of choice.